# Norm of a functional $T:(C[0,1],\lVert\ \rVert_\infty)$→$\mathbb R$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $T:(C[0,1], \lVert\ \rVert_\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $T(f)=\int_0^12xf(x)\,dx$ for all $f\in C[0,1]$. Then prove that $\lVert T\rVert=1$.

I know the definition of vector space $C[0,1]$ and infinite norm $\lVert f(x)\rVert_\infty=\max_{x\in [0,1]}{|f(x)|}$ but that doesn't suffice to prove (or even verify) this. Kindly give a possible geometric approach to visualize this proof or any other concrete logic I am missing completely. Thanks

Comment: **Partial hint:** For $\alpha\ge0$, all functions $$g_\alpha(x):= x^\alpha$$ satisfy $\lVert g_\alpha\rVert_\infty=1$. Can you find $\alpha\ge0$ such that $T(g_\alpha)=1$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f\in\mathcal{C}^0([0,1])$, one has: $$\begin{align}|T(f)|&=\left|\int_0^12xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right|\\&\leqslant\int_0^12x|f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x\\&\leqslant\int_0^12x\|f\|_{\infty}\,\mathrm{d}x\\&=2\|f\|_{\infty}\int_0^1x\,\mathrm{d}x\\&=1\times\|f\|_{\infty}.\end{align}$$
Therefore, $\|T\|\leqslant 1$. Besides, $1\in\mathcal{C}^0([0,1])$, $\|1\|_{\infty}=1$ and $|T(1)|=1$, hence $\|T\|\geqslant 1$. Finally, $\|T\|=1$.

*Reminder.* Let $(E,\|\cdot\|_E)$ and $(F,\|\cdot\|_F)$ be normed vector space. Let $T\in\mathcal{L}_c(E,F)$, one has: $$\|T\|:=\sup_{x\in E,x\neq 0_E}\frac{\|T(x)\|_F}{\|x\|_E}.$$
If $E$ is finite-dimensional, there will always exist $x\in E$ such that $\|T\|=\|T(x)\|_F$, however this result does not hold if $E$ is infinite-dimensional (see the *exercise* below for a counterexample). We are lucky to have found such a vector in your case.

*Exercise.* Let define the following linear map: $$T:\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}(\mathcal{C}^0([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_{\infty})&\rightarrow&(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)\\f&\mapsto &\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1/2}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_{1/2}^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\end{array}\right..$$
Find the norm of $T$. (Hint: Try first to find an upper bound for $\|T\|$ and then find a sequence $(f_n)\subset\mathcal{C}^0([0,1])$ such that $(\|T(f_n)\|_{\infty})$ converges toward this upper bound.)

Comment: @C.Falcon...thanks a lot. Would you like to shed some light on the conclusion "Therefore $||T||\leq 1$".

Comment: We have shown that: $$\forall f\in\mathcal{C}^0([0,1]),|T(f)|\leqslant 1\times\|f\|_{\infty}.$$
Therefore, we have: $$\forall f\in\mathcal{C}^0([0,1])\setminus\{0\},\frac{|T(f)|}{\|f\|_{\infty}}\leqslant 1.$$
Hence, we have found that $1$ is an upper bound for $\frac{|T(f)|}{\|f\|_{\infty}},f\in\mathcal{C}^0([0,1])\setminus\{0\},$ and by definition $\|T\|$ is the least upper bound of this quantity. Is that clearer?

Comment: I mean did u mean $||f||_\infty$=1?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. If you like we can take $f\in\mathcal{C}^0([0,1])$ such that $\|f\|_{\infty}=1$, since an equivalent definition for $\|T\|$ is: $$\|T\|:=\sup_{f\in\mathcal{C}^0([0,1]),\|f\|_{\infty}=1}|T(f)|.$$

Comment: ok..I understand now..thanks a lot for making it clear @C. Falcon.

Comment: I recommend to take a look at the *exercise* I let you, it provides great insight on how to compute a continuous linear operator norm.